# Use of "darum" when it doesn't add any value

Tags: translation

On this page [here](https://www.spektrum.de/news/das-soziale-netzwerk-unserer-proteine/1720944),  I have come across this use of "darum".

> Ob es zur Bindung kommt, lässt sich von außen nicht ohne Weiteres
>   beurteilen. Also griffen die Forscher zu einem Trick: Sie koppelten an
>   das eine Protein ein Molekül, das die Hefen besser wachsen lässt –
>   allerdings erst dann, wenn es selbst aktiviert wird. Den notwendigen
>   Aktivator koppelten sie ***darum*** an Protein zwei.

My translation of this without the "darum" is:

> It is not easy to judge from the outside whether the binding occurs.
>   So the researchers used a trick: with the first protein they coupled a molecule 
>   that allows the yeast to grow better - but only when it itself is
>   activated. They coupled the necessary activator to protein two.

I don't see the point of "darum" here. None of the usual meanings, i.e. "this is why", "about", "around" or "therefore" makes sense.

Comment: What about _therefore_?

Comment: Why does it not make sense? The first protein gets coupled to by a molecule. It is therefore blocked. Hence they need to couple the activator to the second protein.

Comment: So "they activated a molecule to the first protein, and therefore coupled the activator to the second protein" makes sense to you? The first part is not a cause of the second. Two entirely distinct activities.

Comment: No, but that doesn't seem like the correct translation to me because it misses the interdependency. The one is blocked and must be activated. Because of the blocking the second is necessary to achieve the activation. Hope that's correct, chemistry is not my strength. I mean outside of the kitchen :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider the meaning *therefore* as plausible (and do not recognize the argument for your rejection).

- You want to recognize a binding (which is non-obious)
- You attach a something_1 to part 1 and something_2 to part 2
- Since something_1 and something_2 have a measurable interaction when bound, you will be able to deduce that binding from your measurement.

The *darum* indicates, that you need to combine something_2 with part 2, since it is required for the implication chain.

Comment: *Because of this* may also be a valid translation of *darum*.